# Using mobx actions to fetch data/execute async requests

Tags: react-native, mobx

Please advise if it is correct to use mobx actions (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html) to fetch  remote api or do  similar stuff:

```
  @action readSomething() {
    this.observableLoading = true;
    executeRead(
      this.param1,
      mappedData => {
        this.observableData = mappedData;
        this.observableLoading = false;
      },
      () => {
        console.log('error occurred');
      },
    );
  }
```

If the approach does not violate idea behind mobx stores and store's action, how to report fetch errors? Introduce dedicated observable for errors pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that `executeRead` does something asynchronous before running it's second parameter action. In that case it is wrong usage. Action decorator will only apply to the first line in function. You can consult [MobX docs here](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html) about this. What you can be doing instead is use `runInAction`:

```
  @action readSomething() {
    this.observableLoading = true;
    executeRead(
      this.param1,
      mappedData => {
        runInAction(() => {
          this.observableData = mappedData;
          this.observableLoading = false;
        })
      },
      () => {
        console.log('error occurred');
      },
    );
  }
```

Fetch errors definitely can be another observable if you want it to be seen on UI. Your `observableLoading` could instead be `observableState` and hold one of the "loading", "finished" or "error" states.

Comment: Thank you for your answer cannot verify at the moment in order to accept, but up voting.